# Can we use OAuth to authenticate the consumers in my Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am developing a web application, mobile application and desktop application which all can access the data with the help of a single API which can be developed by ASP.NET Web API.

In my Web API can I authenticate the user credentials and the consumer Application key with the help of OAuth?
Can you guys guide me to achieve the same with any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines in startup class

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var oauthProvider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
            {
                OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = async context =>
                {
                    IsValid = true;
//You can get the username and password by context.username and context.password
                    if (IsValid)
                    {
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("user", context.UserName));
                        context.Validated(claimsIdentity);

                        return;
                    }
                    context.Rejected();
                },
                OnValidateClientAuthentication = async context =>
                {
                    string clientId;
                    string clientSecret;
                    if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
                    {
                        if (clientId == GlobalAppSettings.SystemSettings.ApplicationKey)
                        {
                            context.Validated();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            var oauthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/accesstoken"),
                Provider = oauthProvider,
                AuthorizationCodeExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),
                SystemClock = new SystemClock()

            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oauthOptions);

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

    }
```

And invoke the startup method by start up the new OAuth APP from where you need the authorization and OAuth token

You can use your own host by using the self hosting namespace.
Otherwise you can use Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener namespace and host the OAuth app in different host as below

```
var Basesite = "http://localhost:9327/";
            var homeProcessorModel = new HomeProcessorModel();
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: Basesite))
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                   var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
                   {
                       {"grant_type","password"},
                       {"userName",username},
                       {"passWord",password}
                   };//If you are using grant_type as password, you have to send the username and password to OAuth protocol.
                var tokenResponse = client.PostAsync(Basesite + "accesstoken", new FormUrlEncodedContent(form)).Result;
                var token = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<Token>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;
                //You can get the token with token.AccessToken object
            }
```